# Schema.org combination of Product and VideoObject for selling a video?

Tags: e-commerce, schema.org

I'm actually working on a webapp which sells videos. According to Schema.org I can't find a way to combine the `Product` schema with the `VideoObject` schema.

Any best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pockystar from Twitter, it seems that "additionalType" allows to mix schema togethers.

The perfect use case of a book/product is displayed on their website.

https://schema.org/additionalType